# Add a header with two columns in flex inside Select dropdown in React and tailwind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, tailwind-css

Is it possible to add a header with two columns in a select dropdown, as shown in the pic below?
[image]

I tried a few ways but its not rendering. Here is my current code without header and single timeslow column

```
<select className='base mt-2 mx-auto' value={selectedTime} onChange={(e) => {setSelectedTime(e.target.value)}}>
{
 timeslots.timeInterval.map((data,i)=> <option key={i} value={data} 
 className={`${hideTimeSlot(data,1,timezone,selectedDate)}`}> 
 {formatAmPmTime(data)}</option>)
                }
  </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't support for compiling tailwind classes on the fly like you are trying to do so that wouldn't work. In addition to this no you cannot use any sort of formatting like what you're trying to do within [option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#technical_summary). The permitted content per the documentation is: `Text, possibly with escaped characters (like &eacute;).` so even styling wouldn't work in this case.